# Return workers to their home node only when there is no work

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a simulation model with following flow:

source -> seize -> delay -> release -> sink

In the release block, I want to configure the worker to go back to their home/base location only when there is no more agents from the source block.

I have tired 2 configs:

1. Return to home location -> each time: In this case, each worker moves to their home/base location and then go to the source block (which makes sense)
2. Return to home location -> in no other task: In this case, the worker gets stuck at sink node and does not move (either to their base node or to the source node)

How do I make the worker go to the source node if there are more source agents or go to their base node if there is no more agent in the source node?

Comment: In general, the 2nd config you mention should work. How exactly are they stuck at the sink? Where are the resources in the flowchart? When the agent goes to the sink, all its resources should be released. So your worker should be idle... Isn't this happening?

Comment: That problem is solved now, in the seize block I had not defined the agent location, once I set the Agent Location as "source node" the worker went to the source node, the problem now though is, it literally jumps to the source node and doesnt move there through a path